# scroll table inside div not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a table inside container (overflow). Some features of the table:

1 - hover row (hightlighted)

2 - click row and will hightlight on it

3 - double click or enter open window.location

4 - arrow key down / up navigation to hightlighted row (keep it on the middle of container)

5 - when scroll container, the hightlighted row keep on the middle of container

**BUGS:**

*IE*

1 - when scroll container, the hightlighted row not show/work (using arrow key and scroll)

error msg

```
var row_top = $(box).find('table').find('.row-highlight').offset().top; it is null or not is a object
Line: 100
Character: 21
Code: 0
```

*OPERA*

1 - when click on the row and will use arrow key it jump to middle container, not keep sequence of the navigation

2 - key press arrow not working, just when keep click arrow work.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/crazywebLOL/GFgZ6/)**

Comment: could you explain more on this" when scroll container, the hightlighted row not show/work (using arrow key and scroll)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that sets up row-highlighting on mouse hover. This also syncs up the row highlight with the mouse on mouse-wheel. You will probably have to extend this to support synching up after arrow keys as well.

[how to highlight rows in a table on mouse hover ?](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-highlight-rows-in-a-table-on-mouse-hover/)

Answer (score 1):

Krishnan, that is not what i need. I will explain: when i scrolling, i need that middle row into view div will be highlight (selected). For example there is row 1,2,3,4,5 into view, so the row 3 will be highlight. When scroll to down again will show row 6,7,8,9,10, so the row 8 will be highlight. When i say 'highlight' means selected